# Check numerical stabilityand correct the equation

Tags: numerical-methods

I am struggling with a function that supposedly has a numerical error. I checked for consistency which seems to be fine but I couldn't find the stability error nor attempt to correct it.

[image]

where c = 1-r^(-d) and d =[1:100]

The function is struggling with small values of r and I should, therefore, find a way to redefine it but after two days of trial and error I couldn't come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $$1-\cos\theta=2\sin^2\frac\theta2.$$

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer,

I changed the expression to https://imgur.com/a/59ZcqHP and it seemed to do the trick!

Comment: @Yrden: you dropped $d$.